# What is missing in Code Composer Studio Eclipse environment?

Tags: xtext

I imported my DSL compiler as a plugin on Texas Instruments' Code Composer Studio (CCS) 9.0.1.

I created a General Project and then wrote a file with mydsl extension. Eclipse asked me if I wanted to change the project into Xtext project. and I accepted it. Eclipse validated and colored my code properly but there was not any src-gen folder and compiled code in anywhere even if I saved the file. I had added JDT and PDE plugins to Code Composer Studio. Is there any other plugin I should have added? How can I read the errors if any error is dumped in a place?

Comment: you can try to open the host osgi console (+ menu in console view toolbar) and use commands like ss pluginname to find out the id for your plugin and start <id> to see if it can be started. also make sure you have build automatically on. also have a look at the error log view

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I set the build automatically option on, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

Your project has Xtext nature and builder
If the model project is a java project the the model files should reside below a source folder
You have build automatically enabled